# How can we integrate my gmail account inbox messages to my website using asp.net c#? I want to diaplay the details in the webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

'm trying to integrate my asp.net mvc website with my Gmail account and tryin to retrieve the mails and display it into my website. It can read the messages from the inbox but its not showing in my html webpage.

I am trying using Gmail api.`using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;

When my message from inox is read I want it to get display on the website which i CREATED USING ASP.NET.I first want to connect this with ms sql to save all data how to do that

```
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication3.Models;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using WebApplication3.APIHelper;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class EmailController : Controller
    {
       
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Gmail> emailViewModels = GetAllEmails(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostAddress"]);
            return View(emailViewModels);
        }
        private static List<Gmail> GetAllEmails(string HostEmailAddress)
        {
            List<Gmail> EmailList = new List<Gmail>();
            try
            {
               
                GmailService GmailService = GmailAPIHelper.GetService();
                
                UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest ListRequest = GmailService.Users.Messages.List(HostEmailAddress);
                ListRequest.LabelIds = "INBOX";
                ListRequest.IncludeSpamTrash = false;
                ListRequest.Q = "is:unread"; 

                ListMessagesResponse ListResponse = ListRequest.Execute();
                    if (ListResponse != null && ListResponse.Messages != null)
                    {
                        
                        foreach (Message Msg in ListResponse.Messages)
                        {
                           
                            GmailAPIHelper.MsgMarkAsRead(HostEmailAddress, Msg.Id);

                            UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest Message = GmailService.Users.Messages.Get(HostEmailAddress, Msg.Id);
                            
                            Message MsgContent = Message.Execute();

                            if (MsgContent != null)
                            {
                                string FromAddress = string.Empty;
                                string Date = string.Empty;
                                string Subject = string.Empty;
                                string MailBody = string.Empty;
                                string ReadableText = string.Empty;

                                
                                foreach (var MessageParts in MsgContent.Payload.Headers)
                                {
                                    if (MessageParts.Name == "From")
                                    {
                                        FromAddress = MessageParts.Value;
                                    }
                                    else if (MessageParts.Name == "Date")
                                    {
                                        Date = MessageParts.Value;
                                    }
                                    else if (MessageParts.Name == "Subject")
                                    {
                                        Subject = MessageParts.Value;
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                List<string> FileName = GmailAPIHelper.GetAttachments(HostEmailAddress, Msg.Id, Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GmailAttach"]));

                                if (FileName.Count() > 0)
                                {
                                    foreach (var EachFile in FileName)
                                    {
                                        
                                        string[] RectifyFromAddress = FromAddress.Split(' ');
                                        string FromAdd = RectifyFromAddress[RectifyFromAddress.Length - 1];

                                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FromAdd))
                                        {
                                            FromAdd = FromAdd.Replace("<", string.Empty);
                                            FromAdd = FromAdd.Replace(">", string.Empty);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("STEP-3: Mail has no attachments.");
                                }

                                
                                MailBody = string.Empty;
                                if (MsgContent.Payload.Parts == null && MsgContent.Payload.Body != null)
                                {
                                    MailBody = MsgContent.Payload.Body.Data;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    MailBody = GmailAPIHelper.MsgNestedParts(MsgContent.Payload.Parts);
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReadableText))
                                {
                                    Gmail GMail = new Gmail();
                                    GMail.From = FromAddress;
                                    GMail.Body = ReadableText;
                                    GMail.MailDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Date);
                                    GMail.MsgID = Msg.Id; 
                                    EmailList.Add(GMail);
                                }
                                
                                ReadableText = GmailAPIHelper.Base64Decode(MailBody);

                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                
                    return EmailList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.ToString());

                return null;

            }

        }
        
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class Gmail
    {
       
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public DateTime MailDateTime { get; set; }
        public List<string> Attachments { get; set; }
        public string MsgID { get; set; }
        public string TicketNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

how can i display the details in the web page

how can i display the details in the web page using asp.net mvc. I want to store details of every mail read in a list

Comment: You want to create a Table on your webpage and fill with data from the emails.  See : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0524d6/create-table-programmatically-in-Asp-Net/